# Why are my CSS columns glitching when when my column-count is set to 4?

Tags: html, css, laravel, css-multicolumn-layout

I created a profile page to list entries by a user. I copied and pasted the entry list from my general entry list which uses CSS columns. When I use the columns on my profile page, the columns glitch out as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7SxB.jpg).

[This is how it's supposed to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eynDM.jpg)

(Please ignore the fixed navbar)

Here is the HTML markup from the profile page(profile.blade.php) :

```
    <div class="fixed-width" style="margin: 18pt auto;">
    <div class="card-container">
        @foreach ($entries as $entry)
        <a href="{{ action('EntryController@show', [$entry->slug]) }}">
            <article class="card">
                <div style="background-image: url(/storage/{{ $entry->photo->photo() }}); background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>

                <p>{{ $entry->title }}@if(!is_null($entry->alt_title)) ({{ $entry->alt_title }})@endif</p>

                <a href="../categories/{{ $category }}">{{ $category }}</a>

                <p>PIN</p>
            </article>
        </a>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
    .card{
    height: 260pt;
    transition: filter .25s;
    margin-bottom: 18pt;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
    display: block;
}
.card:hover{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(105%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: brightness(108%);
    transition: filter .25s;
}
.card-container{
    -moz-column-width: 225pt;
    -webkit-column-width: 225pt;
    column-width: 225pt;
    column-gap: 18pt;
}
```

For some reason, when I set a column-count style to 3, the columns work properly. However, if I set it to 4 or more, I get the glitch.

Has anyone here encountered this issue? Do you have a solution?

Comment: It is really strange that you are using "pt" instead of "px", "rem" or "em".  I think your problem is that you have the "card" class inside a "root" element... you should have the "article" tag outside the "a" tag ("a" tag should be inside "article" not the other way), try that... "article" will be outside the "a" tag with the class "card".

Comment: @matiaslauriti Ok, trying that now, and the pt sizing is temporary.

Comment: @matiaslauriti That made no difference :(

Comment: The thing is that it is not applying correct height for the even cards... see your css about that